# How to fix Python code returning TypeError: 'str' object is not callable?

Tags: python, http

i've been trying to send a `POST` HTTP request using `Python` (first time using it) and it keeps returning a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

My code:

```
import requests
import json

c100 = "100";
url ="http://api.orange.com/smsmessaging/v1/outbound/tel+21654614211/requests"

payload = {
  "outboundSMSMessageRequest": {
    "address": "tel+21653424499",
    "outboundSMSTextMessage": {
      "message": "Capteur "+ c100 +"  est en incendie"
    },
    "senderAddress": "tel+21654614211",
    "senderName": "GCI"
  }
}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, auth=('Basic <omitted>'), data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    r = requests.post(url, auth=('Basic U0cwUE1aeGZmZ0JLbUkzWUV2ZWlsM0xBdEt0UVZ4Q1k6SVRqWXQxRU5nWlV4SGM5OQ=='), data=payload, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 88, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 433, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 371, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 291, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 470, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: in which line an error occurs?

Comment: Line 18 last line

Comment: Please edit your post to include the entire text of the traceback you get when you try to run the code.

Comment: @JoshKarpel I added the entire text of the traceback in the original post

Answer (score 2):

your Authentication is wrong, and also the question is: do You need authentication at all?

> **Basic Authentication** Many web services that require authentication accept HTTP Basic Auth. This is the simplest kind, and Requests
>   supports it straight out of the box.
>
> Making requests with HTTP Basic Auth is very simple:
>
> ```
> >>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
> >>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
> <Response [200]>
> ```
>
> In fact, HTTP Basic Auth is so common that Requests provides a handy
>   shorthand for using it:
>
> ```
> >>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
> <Response [200]>
> ```
>
> Providing the credentials in a tuple like this is exactly the same as
>   the HTTPBasicAuth example above.

NOTE:

if you have token probably you need something like:

```
import requests

auth_token='sdasadadsadas'
head = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token}
payload = {
  "outboundSMSMessageRequest": {
    "address": "tel+21653424499",
    "outboundSMSTextMessage": {
      "message": "Capteur "+ c100 +"  est en incendie"
    },
    "senderAddress": "tel+21654614211",
    "senderName": "GCI"
  }
}

url = 'http://api.orange.com/smsmessaging/v1/outbound/tel+21654614211/requests'
response = requests.post(url,  json = payload, headers=head)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, the auth token i have doesn't have a user and a pass, it's just a long string of random characters preceded by "Basic"

Comment: Thanks, but i get a TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json' when running

Comment: sorry my mistake , instead try data=json.dumps(payload)

Comment: Thanks, i tried what you posted, i get no output though, i suspect it's working fine though , is there a way to debug and view whether the request was made or no? sorry first time using Python

Answer (score 0):

The authentication parameter in your original code is wrong. If you remove it, it will work.

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```